# How can I add a new property to Component in _app.tsx in Next.js with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm developing some protected pages using Next.js, NextAuth.js and Typescript. The following code from my `_app.tsx` was taken from the NextAuth.js official website but that includes a property `auth` that does not exist for `Component` which has the type `var Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}>`, so TS is displaying an error for that:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        {Component.auth ? (
          <Auth>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Auth>
        ) : (
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        )}
      </SessionProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm not a Typescript expert, so my question is how can I add/extend that `auth` property to the Component with TS?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to extend `AppProp` and add your custom attributes

```
import type { NextComponentType  } from 'next' //Import Component type

//Add custom appProp type then use union to add it
type CustomAppProps = AppProps & {
  Component: NextComponentType & {auth?: boolean} // add auth type
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: CustomAppProps) {
...
}
```

Comment: That worked fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To support the addition of `auth` property on an arbitrary component I made the `NextAuthComponentType`:

```
import { AppPropsType } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/utils';

export type NextAuthComponentType = AppPropsType['Component'] & { auth?: boolean;};
```

In the `_app.tsx` it can be used as:

```
const MyApp: AppType<Props> = ({ Component, pageProps: {...} }) => {
  const AuthComponent = Component as NextAuthComponentType;
  return (
    ...
    {AuthComponent.auth ? (
      <Auth>
        <AuthComponent {...pageProps} />
      </Auth>
    ) : (
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    )}
    ...
```

And the the `auth` can be assigned to the component using:

```
const AuthPreview: NextAuthComponentType = Preview;
AuthPreview.auth = true;

export default AuthPreview;
```

P.S.
Changing `Component` in the `Props` that are passed to the `AppType` doesn't help and TS doesn't recognise the `auth` prop

Answer (score 0):

if some looks for Auth component

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'


  const Auth = ({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) =>{
     const router = useRouter()
     const {status, data} = useSession()
     const isUser = !data?.user
     const loading = status === "loading"

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!loading){
      if(!isUser){
        router.push("/signin")
      }
    }
  },[isUser, loading])

  if(!loading && isUser){
    return <>{children}</>
  }

  return null;
}
```